# PHP error when run

Tags: php, html

I get this error when I run the script and I don't know from where!
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"}"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\install\xampp\htdocs\website\displayupdate.php on line 69

I get the error right after the line of echo at end with that }..

Code is this:

```
  <html>

<?php

//Connect to database
$connect=mysqli_connect("localhost" ,"root", "","asig");

//Select database
mysqli_select_db($connect,'asig');

//Select Query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `customer`,`type`,`valability` WHERE customer.Customer_ID=valability.Customer_ID  AND valability.Insurance_ID=type.Insurance_ID";

//Execte query
$records=mysqli_query($connect,$sql);



?>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<table>
    <tr>
         <th>id</th>
         <th>Nume</th>
         <th>Prenume</th>
         <th>DataNastere</th>
         <th>telefon</th>
         <th>Adresa</th>
         <th>email</th>
         <th>serie</th>
         <th>type</th>
         <th>numeAsig</th>
         <th>Companie</th>
         <th>Valoare></th>
         <th>Numar</th>
         <th>DataIntrare</th>
         <th>DataExpirare</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
     while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($records)){


                       echo "<tr><form action=update.php method=post>";
                      // echo "<td><input type=checkbox name=checkbox[]  value='".$row['Customer_ID']."'></td>";
                       echo "<td><input type=text name =id value='".$row['Customer_ID']."' ></td>";
                       echo "<td><input type=text name= name value='".$row['Name_c']."'> </td>";
                       echo "<td><input type=text name=prenume value='".$row['Surname_c']."'> </td>";
                       echo "<td><input type=text name=brth value='".$row['brth']."'> </td>";
                       echo "<td><input type=text name=phone value='".$row['phone']."'> </td>";
                       echo "<td><input type=text name=adress value='".$row['adress']."'> </td>";
                       echo "<td><input type=text name=email value='".$row['email']."'> </td>";
                       echo "<td><input type=text name=serie value='".$row['series']."'> </td>";
                       echo "<td><input type=text name=type value='".$row['type']."'> </td>";
                       echo "<td><input type=text name=namei value='".$row['name_i']."'> </td>";
                       echo "<td><input type=text name=compn value='".$row['Company_N']."'> </td>";
                       echo "<td><input type=text name=value value='".$row['value']."'> </td>";
                       echo "<td><input type=text name=nr value='".$row['nr']."'> </td>";
                       echo "<td><input type=text name=entryin value='".$row['entry_d']."'> </td>";
                       echo "<td><input type=text name=entryout value='".$row['exp_d']."'> </td>";
                       echo "<td><input type=submit>";

                   echo "</form></tr>"



     }




    ?>  
</table>




</body>


</html>
```

Comment: looks like you missing `;` at the line 69

Comment: The last echo before } needs ; to close line.

Comment: it's not that. i tried putting ; after } but it doesn't work

Comment: Oh yes it is! Silly me ! Thanks a lot. Cought up in the little details :D